# How to discover linux username with administrator privileges in Java

Tags: java, linux, sudo

I created a program which needs administrator privileges to be executed (in this program I am using a port which is <1024).
So I use this command to execute:

```
sudo java -jar example.jar
```

In my program I try to create a folder in this path:

```
Paths.get("/home/" + System.getProperty("user.name"))
```

The problem is that System.getProperty("user.name") answers with "root" and so my new directory is in "/home/root/", but I want it in "/home/my_username".
My question is: how can I discover my username and then create the new folder in the right path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
sudo whoami
```

it responds with

```
root
```

however if I do

```
sudo bash -c 'echo $SUDO_USER'
```

I get

```
peter
```

You do this from Java with

```
String user = System.getenv("SUDO_USER");
if (user == null)
    user = System.getProperty("user.name");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change from

```
Paths.get("/home/" + System.getProperty("user.name"))
```

to the `user.home` [System Property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) like

```
Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"))
```

Comment: @stamina The root user's home folder is `/root`.

Comment: Yes, but if my username is user1 and I'm using sudo when I'm executing my program, I'd like to create the new folder in /home/user1 and not in /root/.<br> my question is: is there a way to "discover" my original username?

Answer (score 0):

Linux user name is normally bound to the `USER` environment variable at `login(1)` time.  The best approach is to use this variable, as other means (running `who(1)` or `id(1)` command for example) all do inspect it (using the `uid` as parameter, to scan files for it).  The same applies for `HOME` and `SHELL` variables.  All of these are collected by `login(1)` on authenticating the user (or by the PAM libraries) and get propagated to all derived processes through the environment.

The weird fact is that you can have several usernames bound to the same `uid`, and not using the environment can lead you to getting the wrong answer (if you scan the `/etc/passwd` file with your `uid` as argument, you can get to a different `passwd(5)` file entry ---of course, with the same `did`)  Use:

```
String username = System.getEnv("USER");
```

for it.

On other side, if you have created a new session (with `sudo(1)` command or similar) and switched both `uid` and `euid` and the environment has been changed (reinitialised), how you distinguish this from a proper login made by `root` account.  In that case there are no traces that the process were invoked by a non-root user.